# Unable to click the button in the webpage

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping

I was developing a web scraping program. Web page has a code segment similar to this.

```
<div id="main" class="c-section">
  <span id="new-fee" class="a-button-primary">
    <span class="a-button-inner">
      <button id="update-fees" class="a-button-text" type="button">Calculate</button>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I Wanted to click the button. So I write this line to do that.

```
   objIE.document.getElementById("update-fees").Click
```

But it didn’t work. So I changed the line as follows.

```
  objIE.document.getElementById("new-fee").Click
```

Then it worked. So why doesn't it work when we use id of the button.

Comment: It depends on which element has the click handler attached to it.

Comment: ^^ that. In html supplied I see no event defined for the click nor association with a form.